# NUnit 3 : How to globally set CurrentDirectory to test assembly's directory

Tags: nunit-3.0

Is there a way to globally set the `CurrentDirectory` to the test assembly's directory? Like a config file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current directory the same way as you would in normal c# code. e.g.

```cs
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
```

If you want to make sure this happens before any of your tests are run, do this in a [SetUpFixture outside of any namespace](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute).